# Docker cleaning up Kubernetes Pod logs too quickly

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am running a number of [CronJobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/) to automate tasks on my home server. When a Job runs and its Pods complete, I can view logs using `kubectl logs <podName>`, however after a certain amount of time (less than 5mins but more than 30s) the Pod still exists in Kubernetes but I get:

```
unable to retrieve container logs for docker://<containerID>
```

I have not enabled any log rotation myself so I assume Docker is cleaning up the logs once the container finishes. How can I configure Docker to retain these container logs so that I can see the Jobs logs after a longer period of time (say 1 day) after the Job completes.

- Cluster provisioner: kubeadm 1.17.0
- Kubernetes version: 1.17.0
- Docker version: 18.06.3-ce
- `uname -r`: 4.19.86-coreos

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting up `minimum-container-ttl-duration` flag in Kubelet. This is  the minimum age for a finished container before it is garbage collected.

Also in the job spec you can specify a TTL

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pi-with-ttl
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
```

The Job pi-with-ttl will be eligible to be automatically deleted, 100 seconds after it finishes.

Comment: Unfortunately `minimum-container-ttl-duration` is deprecated and `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` is alpha (don't really want to use it unless it disappears, also would want the setting to be cluster-wide and not opt in) - the recommended replacement for `minimum-container-ttl-duration` is to use `eviction-hard` but that will let the disk usage get to 85% by default, I want to clear up as much as possible but leave dead pods alone for a day (as was posssible using `minimum-container-ttl-duration` as you mentioned), but can't see how to do that now

Answer (score 0):

According to [(CronJob) PODs are deleted immediately when a job fails](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/cronjob-pods-are-deleted-immediately-when-a-job-fails/4812), I tested these settings will work. You may need to adjust the HistoryLimits to the expected number of runs the cron job will be trigged and the `ttlSecondsAfterFinished`.

```
jobTemplate.spec.backoffLimit = 0
successfulJobsHistoryLimit = 1
failedJobsHistoryLimit = 1
podSpec.restartPolicy = Never
```

Answer (score -1):

Went for a simple CronJob using docker [prune](https://docs.docker.com/config/pruning/)

```sh
docker system prune -f -a --filter "until=168h"
docker volume prune -f
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail how it is related to your initial question ? Does it resolve your issue ?